# What did you think of the Winterbash event?

Tags: discussion, announcement

Winterbash is over with, even if winter itself is just getting started, and the hats have all been put away, possibly for next year.

Stack Exchange would like to know what you thought about this event. Please leave your feedback on [this post on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161188/what-do-you-think-of-winter-bash).

Comment: I had a lot of fun, personally. I met my goal: the Gotta Catch 'Em All! hat. :)

Comment: @jcmeloni, was that the baseball cap? I think I got that one too. They were pretty cool. I liked how most of the hats fit everyone like a kid wearing an adult's hat, covering the face.  Except Oded's chef hat. That fit perfectly.

Comment: It was *Ash Ketchum's* baseball cap :P

Comment: I got lucky with that one :)

Comment: can [tag:featured] be removed from this one?

Comment: Hi @enderland, I believe that once more events occur, either blog articles or more featured posts, this post will disappear from the community bulletin. However, if I remove featured, this will get bumped back up to the top of the active page on meta..... I guess, since this is the only post marked featured, the norm on the Workplace is to remove it manually... so.... it is done! :)

Comment: @jmort253 awesome. I was just noticing it was cluttering the "meta" tages as featured when, well, it's probably not featured anymore :)